# Oracle: column ambiguously defined

Tags: oracle, join, defined

I know there are lots of questions like these, but my question is not how to get rid of this error but to know how this worked earlier in 9-th version of Oracle.

I've got an old sources written in Ruby and Oracle DB which recently was upgraded to version=11.

I cannot edit data in Oracle DB, only read. so there are two tables lets say: table A(id, name, type, customer) and table B(id,a_id,type,person)

so. there is a query in the source code:

```
select a.id,b.id from a join b on a.id = b.a_id where type = 'A'
```

so in Oracle 9 this worked perfectly but now i've got "column ambiguously defined" error.

What i'd like to know is:

```
where type = 'A'
```

is the same as

```
where a.type = 'A' AND b.type = 'A'
```

or

```
where a.type = 'A' OR b.type = 'A'
```

?

Comment: I'm really surprised that it worked in Oracle 9. That query should have never worked.

Comment: Didn't you add the column TYPE to one of the tables in the same process as migrating to Oracle 11? Or maybe a GRANT has made one of the columns visible to you?

Comment: actually i cannot answer this question cause i'm not a DBA. so i just do not know how this db was migrated(

Comment: So i asked DBA and got that info:
old DB version 10.2.0.4.0 - the query worked fine
new DB version 11.2.0.2.0 - i get the error

Comment: please add the real ddl for the two tables, and the real query

Comment: 1) the thing is that all data in a.type and b.type is the same. i mean - i work with test DB. in production db it is possible to have a different data in these columns

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this was a bug with the ANSI style join. Use DBMS_XPLAN to find which table was being filtered in the old database.

Or better still, work out from the business logic what they query SHOULD have been.

Comment: So. thanks all of you for the help. So i finally got to the person who wrote this query long time ago and he explained to me the logic of the query.

Answer (score 5):

No, and that's the problem: It could mean

```
where a.type = 'A'
```

or it could mean

```
where b.type = 'A'
```

with potentially different results; hence the error saying it is ambiguously defined.

Comment: yeah i know. but in oracle 9 there was no such a mistake...so somehow it worked and returned results. so now to avoid this mistake i have to modify the query but i do not understand how this worked earlier.

Comment: @Andrey: Test the ambiguous query in Oracle 9 (where you say it works) and check the output to see which of the two it uses: `where a.type = 'A'` or the `where b.type = 'A'`

Answer (score 2):

I think you should test in Oracle 9 (where you say it works) and compare the output of the ambiguous query:

```
--- Base
select a.id,b.id from a join b on a.id = b.a_id where type = 'A'
```

with both the non-ambiguous ones:

```
--- QueryA
select a.id,b.id from a join b on a.id = b.a_id where a.type = 'A'
```

and:

```
--- QueryB
select a.id,b.id from a join b on a.id = b.a_id where b.type = 'A'
```

---

Something like this would do:

```
select a.id,b.id from a join b on a.id = b.a_id where type = 'A'
MINUS
select a.id,b.id from a join b on a.id = b.a_id where a.type = 'A'
```

(in short):

```
(Base)
MINUS
(QueryA)
```

and then:

```
(QueryA)
MINUS
(Base)
```

If both of the above `MINUS` queries return 0 rows, then BASE query is interpreted as QueryA.

Check similarly and compare Base with QueryB.

---

Another plausible reason for this error is that during (or about the same period with ) the migration, a `type` column was added in the 2nd table. Do you have old versions of the database tables' definitions to check that?

Answer (score 1):

All - keep in mind there was a major change to the optimization engine for 11g.  If you set your query optimizer level to 10.2.x on your 11g instance I bet the query would start working again.

That being said you should provide the alias for it so it's not ambiguous to the database server or the DBA / Developer coming behind you.  :)